# How to Find index include list and filter definition of BTree index in PostGreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-metadata

I have to create a complete view of BTree index list to analyze the performances of each and to flush out abnormal indexes (includes or equivalent) to drop them...

Nevertheless I cannot find a way to have the list of the columns involved in the INCLUDE part of index definition.

Also I need index filter part for indexes having it, but I don't found any information in the tables and views of the pg_catalog definition...

The query I use to try is this is one:

```
SELECT --i.indexrelid, 
       s.nspname AS "TABLE_SCHEMA", tc.relname AS "TABLE_NAME",
       ic.relname AS "INDEX_NAME", m.amname as "INDEX_TYPE",
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(a.attname ||  
                        CASE 
                           WHEN indoption[a.attnum-1] = 3 
                              THEN ' DESC' 
                           ELSE ' ASC' 
                        END ||
                        CASE 
                           WHEN i.indcollation[attnum-1] = 0 
                              THEN '' 
                           ELSE ' COLLATE ' ||
                                 (SELECT collname  
                                FROM   pg_collation  
                                WHERE  oid = i.indcollation[attnum-1])
                        END,  ', ') 
        FROM   pg_attribute AS a
        WHERE  a.attrelid = i.indexrelid) AS "KEY_COLUMN_LIST",
       i.indisunique AS "UNIQUE",
       i.indisprimary AS "PRIMARY_KEY",
       i.indisclustered AS "CLUSTERED",
       i.indisvalid AS "VALID",
       CASE k.contype 
          WHEN 'c' THEN 'CHECK'
          WHEN 'f' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY'
          WHEN 'p' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
          WHEN 'u' THEN 'UNIQUE'
       END AS "CONSTRAINT_TYPE",

-->      ??? AS "INCLUDE_COLUM_LIST" attnum <= 0 suppose to have all other columns...
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(a2.attname,  ', ') 
        FROM   pg_attribute AS a2
        WHERE  a2.attrelid = i.indexrelid
          AND  a2.attnum <= 0) AS "INCLUDE_COLUM_LIST",
-- does not works

-->   ??? AS "FILTER_DEFINITION"
--> I did not find

       pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid) AS "INDEX_DEFINITION"
FROM   pg_index AS i           -- index
       JOIN pg_class AS ic       -- classe index
          ON i.indexrelid = ic.oid
       JOIN pg_class AS tc       -- classe table
          ON i.indrelid = tc.oid          
       JOIN pg_namespace AS s  -- schema
          ON tc.relnamespace = s.oid
       JOIN pg_am AS m         -- type d'index
          ON ic.relam = m.oid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_constraint AS k   -- contraintes associées
          ON i.indexrelid = k.conindid AND i.indkey[0:indnkeyatts-1] = k.conkey
WHERE  m.amname = 'btree'
--  AND  ic.relname LIKE 'x%' --> to match with my sample
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

For my demo I create this table and those indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE TX (A INT, B INT, C INT, D INT, E VARCHAR(32), F INT, G DATE, H BOOLEAN)

CREATE INDEX X1 ON TX (A DESC, B ASC, C DESC)

CREATE INDEX X2 ON TX (A, C) INCLUDE (D, E, F)

CREATE INDEX X3 ON TX (B) WHERE G > '2020-01-01'
```

Of course I could parse the INDEX_DEFINITION but there is no garanty that ever works with a simple SUBSTRING... And I dont' want to incluse Lex and Yacc into a simple query !!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `indnkeyatts` column in [`pg_catalog.pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) can tell you which columns are *key* or *non-key* (payload) as described in the [`create index` doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6))

> `indnkeyatts` `int2`
>
> The number of key columns in the index, not counting any included columns, which are merely stored and do not participate in the index semantics

```sql
SELECT a.attname,
  a.attnum<=(SELECT i.indnkeyatts 
             FROM pg_catalog.pg_index i 
             WHERE i.indexrelid='X2'::regclass::oid) AS is_key
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = 'X2'::regclass::oid 
AND a.attnum > 0 
AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

| attname | is_key |
| --- | --- |
| a | **T** |
| c | **T** |
| d | f |
| e | f |
| f | f |

As to the index predicate, there's a [`pg_get_expr()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.6.3.2.2.6.1.1.1) for that because it's stored as `pg_node_tree`, not regular `text` in `pg_index`:

> `indpred` `pg_node_tree`
>
> Expression tree (in `nodeToString()` representation) for **partial index predicate**. Null if not a partial index.

```sql
SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(i.indpred, i.indrelid, true)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_index i
WHERE i.indexrelid = 'X3'::regclass::oid;
```

| pg_get_expr |
| --- |
| g > '2020-01-01'::date |

[Demo at db<>fiddle with above added to your `select`](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xm_Ut9-3) returns:

| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | INDEX_NAME | INDEX_TYPE | KEY_COLUMN_LIST | UNIQUE | PRIMARY_KEY | CLUSTERED | VALID | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | INCLUDE_COLUM_LIST | FILTER_DEFINITION | INDEX_DEFINITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | tx | x1 | btree | a DESC, b ASC, c DESC | f | f | f | t | *null* | *null* | *null* | CREATE INDEX x1 ON public.tx USING btree (a DESC, b, c DESC) |
| public | tx | x2 | btree | a ASC, c ASC | f | f | f | t | *null* | d, e, f | *null* | CREATE INDEX x2 ON public.tx USING btree (a, c) INCLUDE (d, e, f) |
| public | tx | x3 | btree | b ASC | f | f | f | t | *null* | *null* | g > '2020-01-01'::date | CREATE INDEX x3 ON public.tx USING btree (b) WHERE (g > '2020-01-01'::date) |

---

If `psql` [`\d+` meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-D) can fetch you something, so can you: just start it with [`-E`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-OPTION-ECHO-HIDDEN) and it'll begin to print all queries it used to show you the information you request:

> `-E`
>
> `--echo-hidden`
>
> Echo the actual queries generated by `\d` and other backslash commands. You can use this to study psql's internal operations. This is equivalent to setting the variable `ECHO_HIDDEN` to `on`.

The queries above can be obtained from what you get if you do `\d+` on any of your indexes with `ECHO_HIDDEN` set `on`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have parse the index_def with this SQL code :

```
CASE WHEN POSITION(') INCLUDE (' IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) = 0 
               THEN NULL
            WHEN POSITION(') WHERE (' IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) = 0 
               THEN SUBSTRING(pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid), 
                              POSITION(') INCLUDE (' 
                                       IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) + 11, 
                              CHARACTER_LENGTH(pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) 
                                               - POSITION(') INCLUDE (' 
                                                          IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)
                                                         ) - 11)
            ELSE SUBSTRING(pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid), 
                           POSITION(') INCLUDE (' 
                                    IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) + 11, 
                           POSITION(') WHERE (' 
                                    IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)
                                   ) - POSITION(') INCLUDE (' 
                                                IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)
                                               ) - 11)
       END AS "INCLUDE_COLUMN_LIST",          
       CASE WHEN POSITION(') WHERE (' IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) = 0 
               THEN NULL
            ELSE SUBSTRING(pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid), 
                           POSITION(') WHERE (' 
                                    IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) + 9, 
                           CHARACTER_LENGTH(pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) 
                              - POSITION(') WHERE (' 
                                         IN pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid)) - 9)
       END AS "WHERE_PREDICATE"
```

But I will surely use @Zegarek solution which seems the best !

Comment: Counter-intuitively, parsing things in this case is actually not that unsafe since `pg_get_indexdef()` reconstructs - rather than recalls - the definition, sanitising, case-desensitising and stabilising things. I apologise for my immediate reaction of "that's a bad idea" and then "this was a bad idea and now it hurts my eyes" and I'm changing it to "that's an educated choice of a failover method" and "this is reliable against all odds". I appreciate the fact that you *both* posted the issue *and* worked out a workaround like you said you would, *plus* you shared the workaround.